# Why the function will Future return type can return a object not a Future type?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my test code , the function fetchExchangeRates will return a list object other than the Future as declared as it's return type  , but this code will build well , but if I remove the async keyword , the compile will complains that the type mismatch.

So why the build is OK with the async keyword?

```
class Rate{
  String baseCurrency = '';
  String quoteCurrency = '';
  double exchangeRate = 0;
  
  Rate({required this.baseCurrency,required this.quoteCurrency,required this.exchangeRate});
} 

Future<List<Rate>> fetchExchangeRates() async{
    List<Rate> list = [];
    list.add(Rate(
      baseCurrency: 'USD',
      quoteCurrency: 'EUR',
      exchangeRate: 0.91,
    ));
    list.add(Rate(
      baseCurrency: 'USD',
      quoteCurrency: 'CNY',
      exchangeRate: 7.05,
    ));
    list.add(Rate(
      baseCurrency: 'USD',
      quoteCurrency: 'MNT',
      exchangeRate: 2668.37,
    ));
    print('fetchExchangeRates returns');
    return list;
  }


void main() {
  fetchExchangeRates();
      print('after fetchExchangeRates');
}
```

Comment: check [Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)

Answer (score 0):

because `async` makes your function asynchronous and returns a `Future` type without `async` `Future` not `Future`

use `async` when u want to get asynchronous response with `await`

like

```
Future<void> _foo () async {
  await yourAsynchronousRequest();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @novol, you mean every function with a async keyword will return a Future object by compiler automatically?

Comment: yes, I mean exactly it

Answer (score 0):

if there is no `await` you can remove **`Future` & `async`** both